# Prove that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ at each given $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n(x) = n \cdot x^n(1-x), x\in [0,1]\\ f(x) = 0, x\in[0,1] $

$(1)$ Prove that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ at each given $x\in[0,1]$

$(2)$ Does $f_n \rightrightarrows
$ f on $[0,1]$?

---

- Using the Following Definitions

[image]

**Solution Attempt**

$(1)$ we know that $f_n(0) =0 \text{ and } f_n(1) =0 \\ x\in (0,1) f_n(x) = n \cdot x^n(1-x) \text{ then } \\ \lim_{n\ \rightarrow\infty} x^n = 0 \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \cdot x^n(1-x) =0 \\ \text{ Since } x^n \rightarrow 0 \text{ much faster then than } n \rightarrow \infty \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) =0 \Rightarrow \forall x \in [0,1] = f(x) \forall x \in [0,1] \\ \text{ so (1) } f_n(x) \text{ converges to } f(x) \text{ and each given x} \in [0,1]$

$$(2) \\ M_n = \sup \{ |f_n(x)-f(x)| : x\in [0,1] \} \\ M_n = \sup \{ |nx^n-nx^{n+1}| x\in [0,1] \} \\ \text{we need to find the critical values and maximum} \\ f'_n(x) = nx^n(nx^{-1}-n-1)=0 \\ x =0, \frac{n}{n+1} \\ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(\frac{n}{n+1} ) \\ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \cdot (\frac{n}{n+1})^n - n(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n+1} \\ n [(\frac{n}{n+1})^n - (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n+1}] = \infty\\ \text{hence } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}M_n \neq 0 \\ f_n \neq f \text{ on } [0,1]$$

Is this the correct procedure one can use to solve this problem?

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n-n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right)=\frac1e\ne\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

As Peter-foremen said $f(n/(n+1))=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ which converges to $1/e$ not zero so no uniform convergence